# Change to landscape in Xcode 4.5 iOS 6.0 with status bar

Tags: ios6, statusbar, xcode4.5, landscape-portrait

I've been using Xcode 4.4 for my project for iOS and I wanted one of my screens to be permanently landscape so I used

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

and it worked just fine and since I updated to Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6.0 it didn't work at all so I found out that I have to use the new functions and now I have:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight; 
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
        return YES;
}
```

so now my screen is landscape but the status bar remains in its place like the screen is still in portrait mode.

I don't know how to fix it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented this into the viewWillAppear function and it worked in iOS6:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:YES];`